# form validations in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, jquery-validate, validation

I have form which has 2 sets of fields like Field X and Confirm Field X. Only Field X is part of the model. How can I validate that both x and confirm_x are the same? Can I do this in rails or I have to use javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **validates_confirmation_of** in your model. From the API:

```
Model:
  class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_confirmation_of :user_name, :password
    validates_confirmation_of :email_address,
                              :message => "should match confirmation"
  end

View:
  <%= password_field "person", "password" %>
  <%= password_field "person", "password_confirmation" %>
```

Comment: NOTE: This check is performed only if password_confirmation is not nil, and by default only on save. To require confirmation, make sure to add a presence check for the confirmation attribute: `validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :if => :password_changed?`